# what is .ICEAuthority file in opensuse 11.2

Tags: files, opensuse

what is .ICEAuthority file in opensuse 11.2?

Comment: What appears to be a simple question is proving very difficult to find anything about. It has something to do with authority, I think authentication token for X server, but the man page for iceauth has nothing of any use. I have modded this up because I am now determined to find out more. You have engaged my interest.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Here](http://www.xfree86.org/current/ice.pdf) is a good paper on what ICE is, and what it does.

Basically ICE is a inter process communication protocol, with authentication, protocol negotiation and potentially multiplexing built in.

It allows two X clients to talk directly to each other, for example, a video player program could potentially talk to a jukebox program to update each other.

As Richard Holloway says, the .ICEAuthority file is for authentication. It contains a number of random cookies. If two programs have the same cookie, then they're allowed to talk to each other. In practice this either means that they're reading the same .ICEAuthority file, or the cookies have been added.

In a lot of ways it's similar to the xauth program & the .Xauthority file, except that .ICEAuthority is used for client to client, while .Xauthority is for client to server.

Comment: do we have ui for configurating this in opensuse 11.2.

Answer (score 1):

You have installed and ran Klamav, I get the same error after installing and updating from the command line. Sudo klamav or sudo freshklam. Here is a fix:
mv ~/.ICEauthority ~/.ICEauthority.backup
sudo chown {user}:{user} /home/{user}
sudo reboot